# Negative energy quanta vs antimatter approach

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, cpt-symmetry

Consider 2 physical scenarios:

|  | $t_{-1}$ | $t_0$ | $t_1$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sc.1 | electron and positron approached | electron and positron annihilated | photons emitted |
| Sc.2 | electron is free | electron emits some photons | electron is free and of **negative** energy |

So, Sc.1 dropped from 2 fermions to 0, while Sc.2 pictures transformation of the same 1 electron.

My question is, how these 2 scenarios might be equivalent if they leaving us with different amounts of quanta?

I mean, this "of negative energy" electron from Sc.2 is still able to interact with other particles at later times, right?.. Unlike 0 fermions from Sc.1, which will definitely not.

Comment: your second scenario is just a scenario, not physics, because energy  and momentum conservation have to be always obeyed, and an electron cannot just radiate a photon without violating energy and momentum conservation in the center of mass of  electron-photon

Comment: What is the lower bound to your second scenario however? That was the big issue with negative energy, what keeps the electron from radiating indefinitely to arbitrarily large negative energies?

Comment: @annav I suppose I got something wrong in my source then; may be the situation was that positive energy electron went back in time vs also positive energy yet anti-electron going forward. So, it was about CP (or just T) transformation!

Comment: @Triatticus idk; may be it's time interval?..

Comment: @Triatticus I'm brand new to negative energies, but I'm not even sure if you're serious about your question: it seems that you mixed up electron orbitals with mass-energy relation; in which case, ha-ha.

Comment: @VictorNovak no I haven't. Remember that a system will tend to its lowest energy state if there is a mechanism that allows it. If your electron can go to a negative energy state then there isn't a lowest state and it can radiate arbitrarily large amounts of energy away.

Comment: @Triatticus okay! So, I've been reminded of the Dirac see that claimed to resolve this via Pauli exclusion principle (filling all negative energy levels with anti-electrons). However I always skipped that part because it's never been mentioned as a final conclusion, and now I see in Wikipedia that there are many developments, including relations to the Higgs mechanism.